# Setter method for BigDecimal Array

Tags: java, arrays, bigdecimal

I want to create a setter method for BigDecimal array but I can't get the right way of assigning a value for it. I want my array to contain at least a "zero" element or none for the mean  time.

```
public void setAddends(BigDecimal addends[]){
    addends[] = BigDecimal.ZERO;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you're trying to achieve this. Looks like a horrible idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
BigDecimal addends[] = new BigDecimal [10]; 

...

public void setAddends(BigDecimal addends[]){
addends[0] = BigDecimal.ZERO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put some constraints on the input parameter, you should require the caller of the method to provide a valid parameter instead of changing it inside the method. Consider throwing `IllegalArgumentException` if the parameter is invalid.

As far as I understood, you want the array to either contain at least one zero or contains nulls only:

```
public void setAddends(BigDecimal[] addends) {
    if (numberOfNonNullsIn(addends) != 0 && numberOfZerosIn(addends) == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("addends should either contain at least one zero or contain nulls only");
    }

    // ...
}

private long numberOfZerosIn(BigDecimal[] addends) {
    return Arrays.stream(addends).filter(a -> a != null && a.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0).count();
}

private long numberOfNonNullsIn(BigDecimal[] addends) {
    return Arrays.stream(addends).filter(a -> a != null).count();
}
```